# Dropbox oAuth instant 302 redirect

Tags: oauth-2.0, dropbox-api

I'm trying to get an access token from Dropbox, it works on localhost, not on a live server.

The Dropbox oauth grant screen doesn't get show, instead Dropbox returns a 302, here's the response:

[image]

I sending the user to: `https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?redirect_uri=https://app.qwert.com/api/integration/dropbox/auth&response_type=code&client_id=xyz&state=1` (obviously I've changed the clientId and domain...)

Any reason I would get a 302 redirect when exactly the same things works on localhost? (I have set the redirect URI correctly, but even I haven't I should still get to an error page on Dropbox rather then being instantly redirected).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that on localhost Dropbox forces authentication every time you hit the URL. For other domains if the user has authenticated already they get instantly redirected. You can force re-authenication using `force_reapprove` as described here:

> **force_reapprove** Whether or not to force the user to approve the app
>   again if they've already done so. If false (default), a user who has
>   already approved the application may be automatically redirected to
>   the URI specified by redirect_uri. If true, the user will not be
>   automatically redirected and will have to approve the app again.